# Pyspark integration with Jupyter

Tags: pyspark, jupyter

I have installed Anaconda(python 2.7 version) in my machine and started the jupyter notebook with "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter" and PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook" by this i' am connecting to jupyter notebook but unable to run "print" command also. when i' am running the command it is going to the next line but not showing the output and print is not highlighted in color.

Already I have installed pyspark and running in command prompt in my windows machine(standalone mode) and its working fine.....but i need to run in jupyter notebook(windows). Can anybody help me??

Comment: Are you experiencing any errors? Can you create a SparkContext in your notebook?

Comment: Is the SparkContext getting shutdown??

Comment: no errors at all just not displaying the output just simply it is going to the next line when i'am running.

Comment: @RahulLakhanpal The "print sc" statement also not working

Answer (score 1):

This is all what you need to do to setup Pyspark with Jupyter on windows when you already have pyspark shell correctly setup as you mentioned.

1. Add 2 new environment variables, set

   - `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` to jupyter
   - `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` to notebook
2. Run `pyspark` from CMD prompt and not '`jupyter notebook`'

This should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For latest setup, view their official jupyter docker repo.

It's Jupyter 4.x with Spark 2.1.0, Hadoop 2.7

```
docker run -it --rm -p 8888:8888 jupyter/pyspark-notebook
```

[Jupyter Notebook Python, Spark, Mesos Stack](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook)

As side notes,

[1](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook) jupyter use config file, whereas, ipython use profile. I believe if you want to run spark standalone locally. Take a look at Dockerfile and figure out what's the magic.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwBlq.png) more gold in https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks

[image]